# How to implements a wildcard argument properly?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am trying to write a simple generic class `Operations<T extends Number>`, that has a single method `T sum()`. It is supposed to take any `Number` object and return its sum with `T`. I have a strong suspicion that I should use bounded wildcard argument, but I have no idea how to proceed.

```
interface OperationsInterface<T extends Number> {

    public T sum(Operations<? extends Number> v);

}

class Operations <T extends Number> 
    implements OperationsInterface<T> {

    private T o;

    public Operations(T o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public T sum(Operations<? extends Number> v) {

    }

}
```

Comment: i think your code will not have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need: `? extends Number` as a type parameter of method parameter.
Your interface can be like this:

```
interface OperationsInterface<T extends Number> {

    public T sum(T... t);

}
```

since you cannot pass type argument that's not a subclass of `Number`.

And your implementation class like this i.e.:

```
class Operations implements OperationsInterface<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer sum(Integer... t) {
        // do sum
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bind the parameters to `T` then you can of course just do

```
interface OperationsInterface<T extends Number> {

    public <N extends Number> T sum(Operations<N> v);

}

class Operations <T extends Number> 
    implements OperationsInterface<T> {

    private T o;

    public Operations(T o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public <N extends Number> T sum(Operations<N> v) {

    }

}
```

And see if that works for you.